# Sailjs - Can I populate associations via a querystring parameter?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm playing around with the SailsJS beta and want to know if I can populate associated models via a querystring parameter (by default).
  I tried

```
http://localhost:1337/firstModel?populate=secondModel
```

but no luck.
  Is this something I'll have to wire up myself or do I just have the syntax wrong?

--Dave

Comment: If you're using the blueprint `find` or `findOne` methods, then all associated models should be populated by default.

Comment: @ScottGress thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I hadn't defined my attributes so they weren't being added. After adding them into the model file all is well.

Comment: @ScottGress sorry to double up on one question, but is there a way to declare which fields I want to come back? especially if all the associations are getting auto-populated, I'm afraid my payload might get pretty big.

Comment: The default blueprint methods will return everything.  You can always override those methods to have them return anything you want; just declare a `find` or `findOne` method in `FirstModelController.js`.